# how to customize bootstrap datatable search box and records view position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a problem when i was create datatable with bootstrap styling. i got datatable from this site (http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)

i found less in accordance with the view that I have created. I make the navbar above table. so I want to make search box and view the records I put in navbar-right. as this is what I want.

before:
[image]

i want to be like this

[image]

how to customize this? where the javascript code that must be changed or just enough customization with jquery?

Comment: The search box is probably on the header, not inside the datatable, you need to use custom html for this.

Comment: You should put your code in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

read carefull then come and read the rest of the comment
here is an example:

when you understand write

```
     $('#example').dataTable({


      "dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
    }


      );
});
```

this will make the search box has a class named "search" and leave everthing else as it is
now you can easily edit the position of the search box using css
if you want to do like the picture you posted just write

```
"dom":' <"search"fl><"top">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
```

Answer (score 5):

"sDom":'**<"dropdown"l>**'

and css:

.dropdown 
{
    **float: right;**
}